# Solvable groups in which all subgroups are supplemented

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a solvable group in which all non-trivial subgroups are supplemented. (A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called supplemented if $G=HK$ for some proper subgroup $K$. Such a subgroup $K$ is called a supplement of $H$ in $G$). Suppose further that $G$ has a maximal subgroup $M$ having only finitely many supplements in $G$.

Is $G$ necessarily finite?

Comment: Dear Prof. Abdollahi, I am thinking about $Q_8 \times G$, where $G$ is a suitable infinite abelian poly-cyclic group. Did you examined such groups?   

Comment: @Shahrooz: You mean if one takes $G=Q_8\times A$ for a suitable infinite finitely generated abelian group $A$, then $G$ may satisfy conditions given in my question? I think these such groups cannot be counterexample for my question, as the question has positive answer for supersolvable groups. Note that abelian polycyclic groups are exactly finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: Dear Prof. Abdollahi, after some attempts, I could not find suitable $A$.